# TextFieldParser With Fields Enclosed in Something Other Than "

Tags: .net, parsing

.NET

With TextFieldParser can assign the delimiter.

But Enclosed is boolean

[TextFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes.aspx)

How can I specify like ® for the enclosed.

If the answer is to read each line and then split then do NOT provide that code.
I already have a "manual" parser.
My question is if I can use TextFieldParser.

Comment: Ah... took me a minute to realize that "But Enclosed is boolean" is referring to the 'HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes' property having a boolean data type (rather than the text enclosed within the quotes being a string representation of a boolean value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextFieldParser` class only supports double quotes (`"`)  for enclosing. There is no way to change this.

Comment: Oh well was worth asking.  Will wait for a miracle answer before giving this the check.

Answer (score 2):

This [Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) library on CodePlex supports a customized "Quote Character", which could be set to ®.  You could use this instead of `TextFieldParser`, which only supports double quotes for enclosing records.

Comment: Since my manual is running will just stay with it.  Not having performance issues.   I was hoping to simplify code.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all the `®` characters with `"` characters before calling the `TextFieldParser`. Either by preprocessing the file on disk, or using some sort of wrapping `TextReader`. Here's an example of one I wrote:

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapping text reader that transforms each line of text with 
/// the supplied deleagte before it is read.
/// </summary>
public class TransformingTextReader : TextReader
{
    private readonly TextReader _innerReader;
    private readonly Func<string, string> _lineTransform;
    private StringReader _lineReader;

    public TransformingTextReader(TextReader innerReader, 
        Func<string, string> lineTransform)
    {
        _innerReader = innerReader;
        _lineTransform = lineTransform;
        _lineReader = new StringReader(string.Empty);
    }

    public override int Read()
    {
        // Read next character in line
        var result = _lineReader.Read();

        // If end of line (or beginning of stream)
        if (result == -1)
        {
            // Read line from underlying reader
            var line = _innerReader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                // Transform the line, and begin reading its characters
                line = _lineTransform(line) + "\r\n";
                _lineReader = new StringReader(line);
                result = _lineReader.Read();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
         base.Dispose(disposing);
         if (disposing)
         {
             // Make sure we dispose the underlying reader as well
             _innerReader.Dispose();
         }
     }
}
```

This would allow you to do something like the following:

```
var fileReader = new StreamReader(path);
var transformingReader = new TransformingTextReader(fileReader, 
    s => s.Replace('®', '\"'));
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(transformingReader)
{
    // Your code
}
```

**Update**: Here's an example of how you can use the TransformingTextReader to escape inner quotes (in reference to my comment):

```
    // Use regex to escape quotes not adjacent to a delimiter
    var pattern = "(?<=[^,])\"{1,2}(?=[^,])";
    var replacement = "\"\"";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var transformingReader = new TransformingTextReader(fileReader, 
        s => regex.Replace(s, replacement));
```

Of course you can chain together multiple `TransformingTextReader` instances to perform multiple transforms. ;-)

Comment: Yes could replace " with ® but the reason for the ® is some of the fields have " as part of the field.  Even "," can occur in the field.

Comment: Yeah, I've had to deal with that as well. You can escape quotes for the parser by doubling them, i.e. `""` is interpreted as a literal `"`. I'll update my example to include an example how I used my `TransformingTextReader` to deal with files that didn't properly escape quotes.

Comment: Just split each line on ®,® then just trim the ® on the first and last is less code.